# Question about outer measure of symmetric difference

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

According to [Royden], there is a theorem;

> Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite outer measure. Then, for each $\epsilon$, there is a finite disjoint collection of open intervals $\{I_k\}^n_{k=1}$ for which if $\Delta=\bigcup^n_{k=1} I_k$, then 
>   $m^*(E-\Delta)+m^*(\Delta -E)<\epsilon$

The theorem demands the finite outer measure of $E$ to apply exision property. My question is whether this theorem holds without the finite outer measure of $E$. If there is any counterexample, I want to know...!

Comment: How about $E = \cup_{k\in\Bbb{Z}} [k, k+\frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: I got it, thanks!